# Implementing lock and release on firebase data

Tags: angularjs, firebase, locking

I want to use Firebase to build an app for ticket purchases. I envision storing the inventory of tickets on the servers and requirements to be:

1. Allow user to reserve ticket while processing the payment (ie lock
   the ticket)
2. Release the ticket after a certain amount of time if not purchased
3. Prevent dual purchase of same inventory item

I'm concerned about how this would be possible without server-side code where the individual clients are controlling the locks and releases. I suppose the client can keep track of how long its been since the ticket was reserved and then release it. But what if the client disconnects? Would I successfully be able to release locks on tickets using `.onDisconnect()` for example when user loses connectivity?

Comment: While Firebase security rules can go a long way to implement a locking system, you might want to reconsider including your own backend in your solution - you shouldn't trust your client-side to handle payment, for example. And because of that, this question is too broad IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Add an .onDisconnect() which deletes the lock when the user loses connectivity.

That is exactly what .onDisconnect() does, the action is triggered on the server-side when the client connection stops.

But you might want to consider what happens if the client loses the connection temporarily, e.g. if their train goes through a tunnel